# iCloud and iWork issues on Ubuntu 22.04 (not responding)

Tags: gnome, software-installation, wayland, 22.04

Lately, I've installed Ubuntu as a secondary OS on my PC. I keep most of my data and projects on iCloud Drive and I am also very used to the Apple iWork office suite hence I wanted to connect them with my new OS.

Unfortunately, after installing the iCloud package using Ubuntu Software (Snap Store). I am unable to run any of the items (Drive, Pages, Keynote, etc). All I get is e.g:

```
"iCloud Drive" is not responding.
You may choose to wait a short while for it to continue or force the application to quit entirely.
```

Of course, even after hitting the `Wait` button multiple times - nothing is changing.

I've run the Drive from the command line to hopefully get some in-depth error or data.

I've got something like this:

```
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
Sandboxing disabled by user.
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 11 (BadAlloc), sequence: 436, resource id: 77594630, major code: 146 (Unknown), minor code: 7
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 437, resource id: 77594633, major code: 146 (Unknown), minor code: 4
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 11 (BadAlloc), sequence: 456, resource id: 77594638, major code: 146 (Unknown), minor code: 7
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 457, resource id: 77594641, major code: 146 (Unknown), minor code: 4
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 4 (BadPixmap), sequence: 459, resource id: 77594641, major code: 54 (FreePixmap), minor code: 0
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 136 (Unknown), sequence: 460, resource id: 77594642, major code: 134 (Unknown), minor code: 17
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 11 (BadAlloc), sequence: 545, resource id: 77594655, major code: 146 (Unknown), minor code: 7
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 546, resource id: 77594658, major code: 146 (Unknown), minor code: 4
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 4 (BadPixmap), sequence: 551, resource id: 77594658, major code: 54 (FreePixmap), minor code: 0
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 136 (Unknown), sequence: 552, resource id: 77594659, major code: 134 (Unknown), minor code: 17
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 11 (BadAlloc), sequence: 558, resource id: 77594651, major code: 146 (Unknown), minor code: 7
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 559, resource id: 77594661, major code: 146 (Unknown), minor code: 4
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 4 (BadPixmap), sequence: 561, resource id: 77594661, major code: 145 (Unknown), minor code: 1
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 11 (BadAlloc), sequence: 563, resource id: 77594651, major code: 146 (Unknown), minor code: 7
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 564, resource id: 77594663, major code: 146 (Unknown), minor code: 4
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 4 (BadPixmap), sequence: 565, resource id: 77594663, major code: 145 (Unknown), minor code: 1
```

Unfortunately, I am not that familiar with Linux / Ubuntu to find out what is wrong. Has anyone encountered such a problem or has any ideas on how to resolve it?

Thank You all in advance!

My system info: 
OS Name: **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS** 
OS Type: **64-bit** 
GNOME Version: **42.0** 
Windowing System: **Wayland**

Comment: Have you enabled additional permissions?